# How to remove duplicated list from a list of list?

Tags: java

Is there some elegant ways to remove duplicated list (list with same values) from a list of list?

I tried with `Set<List<Integer>>` but it's not working, it still shows the duplicated lists. It seems that `Set` only checks the object reference.

the example code:

```
    int[] nums = {-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4};
    Set<List<Integer>> set = new HashSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
            for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
                if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                    set.add(Arrays.asList(nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

then the set will contain 3 elements but two of them have the same values.

Comment: Are the lists mutable or immutable?

Comment: "t seems that Set only checks the object reference." <- No, as the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) clearly states: "A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element." - So are you sure that your Lists are equal according to the rules of their equals-implementation?

Comment: Post your code so we can reproduce your situation. This seems like an interesting question but it's impossible to understand exactly what you're trying to accomplish without having your code.

Comment: Hi I updated with example code

Comment: @hawarden_ Your problem is: [Two lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) - In your example you will produce the Lists `[0, 1, -1]` and `[-1, 0, 1]` which contain the same elements but not in the same order and hence aren't considered equal. I'm not sure if there is some easy existing way to filter out the duplicates according to your rules, but I would guess you will probably have to write the logic yourself.

Answer (score 0):

A repair:

```
record Triple(int x, int y, int z) {};
int[] nums = {-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4};
Set<Triple> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        for (int k = j + 1; k < nums.length; k++) {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] + nums[k] == 0) {
                set.add(new Triple(nums[i], nums[j], nums[k]));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However the algorithm is suboptimal O(n³).

```
record Triple(int x, int y, int z) {};
int[] nums = {-1, 0, 1, 2, -1, -4};
Arrays.sort(nums);
Set<Triple> set = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    int numI = num[i];
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
        int numJ = num[j];
        int numK = -(numI + numK);
        int k = Arrays.binarySearch(nums, j + 1, nums.length, numK);
        if (k >= 0) { // Found
            set.add(new Triple(numI, numJ, numK));
        }
    }
}
```

`binarySearch` delivers a non-negative index when it finds the search key. When negative, it delivers the 1s complement of the "insert" position.

This has complexity O(n².log n). You determine the found resp. insert position in the for-i loop and in the for-j loop decrement k a couple of times to find the sum. That would not be difficult but less readable.

Mind the resulting numbers are ordered.